# jQuery DatePicker calendar not working in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, jquery-ui-datepicker

This question is [**referencing a previous post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889780/jquery-datepicker-calendar-not-returning-correct-month/) that was answered. Now the problem... it's not working in IE8. It's working perfectly in Chrome and Firefox.

In IE8, the calendar will appear, with the current day highlighted. It doesn't seem to be loading my XML so the events can appear in the calendar.

Does anyone have any idea why this will not work in IE8?  Thank you.

Comment: FYI... I've referenced a few different versions on jQuery UI 8 library. None fix the issue in IE8.

Answer (score 0):

So after much research, and guidance by users @Andrew Whitaker and @Qlimax, I found that IE was not happy with the way I was pulling in the date from my XML file.

I changed my getSelectedDates function to parse the published date so that IE was happy with it. (Chrome and Firefox are still happy too.)

```
function getSelectedDates() {
    return $(data).find('entry').map(function() {
        var dateStr = $('published', this).text();
        var a = dateStr.split("T");
        var d = a[0].split("-");
        var t = a[1].split(":");

        return {
            title: $('title', this).text(),
            published: new Date(d[0],(d[1]-1),d[2])
        };
    }).get();
}
```